# Word to describe learning or understanding something earlier then most

Tags: vocabulary

I remember reading of a word that was used to describe it when a person or thing is able to adopt or learn a concept earlier then most people. I also remember hearing this word in the *Imitation Game*, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up remember what it was:

**Precocious**: (of a child) having developed certain abilities or proclivities at an earlier age than usual.

Answer (score 0):

**Wunderkind**: often used derisively. A person whose academic, or other, achievements belie his or her age. A child prodigy.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wunderkind?s=t

Comment: They're not equal. Wunderkind is a lot funnier.