# What is another way to say "Mature in thinking"

Tags: word-choice

So my sentence is

> X has showed me a maturity in thinking beyond his age.

However, I find it very weird. Do we have another way to say the sentence ?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The linked question is about someone who visually appears older than his age.

Comment: Proofreading or writing advice requests are out of scope and may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Then the linked question is unclear because the title misleads. The title should be corrected or the question closed for revision. We still should not be linking this question to it.

Comment: @MετάEd Perhaps [Word to describe learning or understanding something earlier then most](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284394/word-to-describe-learning-or-understanding-something-earlier-then-most/284400#284400)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree with that one.

Comment: Neither of the two suggested duplicates fits.  One is about physical appearance.  The other is about facility in learning, which does not necessarily have anything to do with mature thinking.  OTH, the OP hasn't distinguished which he means.

Comment: Describing matured mental acuity and the way someone can look more distinguished than others WRT their age are quite different. Distinguished is my looks-related pick. Describing an individual as being exceptionally keen in terms of their insight and perspective doesnt so much point to the age-related aspect, though the practice of elevating your thoughts transcends age to begin with-it shows grace and composure which are indicative of hightened maturity and the ability to evenly cope with a variety of emotions and circumstances without ill effect.  All a matter of experience IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about X's scholarly potential or do you want to indicate X's broader skills?  I think "precocious" is mostly used for various intellectual, musical or even athletic metrics. You can be intellectually precocious and still lack maturity. The brainy, precocious nerd with zero social skills and minimal emotional development is not entirely a television creation.

You can say *X showed a maturity beyond his years*, and everyone will understand that you are not referring to X's physical development, but to X's ability to cope with events and concepts in an adult-like manner.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for ***[precocious](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/precocious):***

> - unusually advanced or mature in development, especially mental development:
>   *a precocious child.*

Dictionary.com

- X showed me how precocious he/she was.